# XML namespaces - how to get them?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Been trying to extract some XML with namespaces in it. I've tried to understand this myself; but I can't seem to identify exactly whats wrong with what I'm doing.

I have this set to variable `$myXMLData`, and running the following code to spit out the title attribute:

```
$myXMLData=<<<XML
<getmatchingproductresponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
  <getmatchingproductresult asin="055726328X" status="Success">
    <product>
       <attributesets>
        <ns2:itemattributes xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd" xml:lang="en-US">
          <ns2:studio>lulu.com</ns2:studio>
          <ns2:title>You Are a Spiritual Healer</ns2:title>
        </ns2:itemattributes>
      </attributesets>
      <relationships>
      </relationships>
   </product>
  </getmatchingproductresult>
  <responsemetadata>
    <requestid>4304bf06-acd2-4792-804a-394a2e01656f</requestid>
  </responsemetadata>
</getmatchingproductresponse>

XML;

$sxe=new SimpleXMLElement($myXMLData);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('ns','http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01');
$result=$sxe->xpath('//ns:title');
foreach ($result as $title)
  {
  echo $title . "<br>";
  }
```

But my output is blank. What am I doing wrong here? Please help...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did register the wrong namespace in the nopaste. Here are two namespaces in the document.

- `http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01`
   
  elements without a prefix
- `http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd` 
  element with prefix ns2

The `title` uses the prefix `ns2`. You don't have to register the prefixes used in the document. You can and should just register you own. In SimpleXML you will have to do that on any element you like to call the method xpath() on. It helps creating a small function for it.

```
$xmlns = [
  'p' => 'http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01',
  'pd' => 'http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd'
];

function registerNamespacesOnElement(
  SimpleXMLElement $element, array $namespaces
) {
  foreach ($namespaces as $prefix => $namespace) {
    $element->registerXpathNamespace($prefix, $namespace);
  }
}

$sxe=new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
registerNamespacesOnElement($sxe, $xmlns);
$result=$sxe->xpath('//pd:title');
foreach ($result as $title) {
  echo $title . "<br>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
You Are a Spiritual Healer<br>
```

Comment: Hi @ThW,
I just realized the Amazon API call doesn't have `<<<XML` and `XML` at the beginning and the end of the XML data it gives me.. I've tried using your code and I'm still getting a blank screen on my localhost :( Maybe its different from the eval.in... but would the API call itself already have the `XML` tags in place already?

Comment: The $variable = <<<KEYWORD ... KEYWORD; is a special string syntax in PHP and other languages (Perl for example). It allows for multiline strings literals with less escaping - it is an alternative syntax to `$variable = "..."`.

Comment: In this case, would my $variable be able to be parsed? Why didn't it work in this case then?

Comment: could you provide some guidance please?

Comment: Like I wrote, you did register the wrong namespace: https://eval.in/615011

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your **header** to be `text/xml`? By default PHP sets the Content-Type to to text/html, so browser tries to display your XML like it is HTML. That's why you probably get blank result.

Try adding this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Register namespace, set in xml declaration
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('ns2','http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd');
// And use the same prefix as in xml
$result=$sxe->xpath('//ns2:title');
```

**[demo](https://eval.in/614583)**

Or in this way

```
$ns = $sxe->getNamespaces(true);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('ns2',$ns['ns2']);
$result=$sxe->xpath('//ns2:title');
```

**[demo](https://eval.in/614589)**